# Qual è il significato di "stemperare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Sulla piscina, Laughton aveva scaricato i suoi estri bizarri, facendone un calidarium con raffinati sistemi di regolazione termica. Là si inerpicavano in processione giovani attori desiderosi di **stemperare** le dizioni regionali, o attori fatti alle prese coi problemi del verso classico.

Ho cercato il [significato di "stemperare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stemperare/) in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il senso di questo verbo nel brano precedente. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Penso sia questa la definizione di Treccani.it che corrisponde all'uso fatto nel brano:

> - In senso fig., far perdere di vigore, di intensità, di efficacia.

Nel contesto si riferisce allo smussare, al rendere meno evidenti le dizioni regionali, ossia gli accenti locali.

Answer (score 0):

In questo passaggio si intende che gli attori di cui parla erano intenti a addolcire , rendere meno evidente il proprio accento di provenienza.
Stemperare in generale significa raffreddare qualcosa di caldo, e analogamente rendere meno forte una qualsiasi situazione difficile.

Comment: Uhmmmm... questa definizione non appare nel Treccani!

Comment: ti aspetti che tutto ciò che non è nella treccani non sia corretto?

Comment: Certo che no, ma mi sembra un po' strano che quello che tu affermi di essere la definizione generale non si trovi nel Treccani.

Comment: etimologicamente l'origine del verbo fa riferimento alla situazione fisica di abbassamento della temperatura. Altri dizionari online lo riportano.

Comment: Se è possibile aggiungi una citazione quando ti riferisci ad altri dizionari online (che mostri il significato come lo intendi tu). Così OP può aggiungerlo alla propria lista dei dizionari da consultare.